# File watcher for less in grunt not updating css

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, less

I have the following gruntfile.js code:

```
less: {
   development: {
      files: [{
         expand: true,
         cwd: 'assets/less',
         src: ['*.less'],
         dest: 'wwwroot/content/css/',
         ext: '.css'
      }]
   }
},
watch: {
   less: {
      files: ["assets/less/*.less"],
      task: ["less:development"]
    }
};


grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-less");
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
```

When I run the watch task and make changes on any of my less files, it detected the changes in the less files:

> > File "assets\less\abc.less" changed.

But the problem is it is not updating my abc.css file. Does anyone know why is this and how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh... just had [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443188/grunt-watch-and-stylus/27445914#27445914) with this issue, and it's the same problem:

```
watch: {
   less: {
      files: ["assets/less/*.less"],
      tasks: ["less:development"]    // <-- note that this is PLURAL! :)
    }
}
```